# Existence of a supporting hyperplane

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis

In $\mathbb R^n$, let $C$ be a closed convex set not equal to $\mathbb R^n$ itself.

I'd like to prove that the boundary of C: $\delta C$ is the set of all supporting points of $C$.

For the first inclusion, let $z\in \delta C$ .

So as to prove that $z$ belongs to  the set of all supporting points of $C$, I think I have to prove the existence of $a \in \mathbb R^n \setminus C$ such that the projection of $a$ on $C$ is $z$.

How to build such an $a$ ?

I know that a sequence $x_n :\mathbb N \rightarrow\mathbb R^n \setminus C$ such that $x_n \rightarrow z$ exists, but it doesn't help much...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It does help that you can find the sequence $x_n \to z$, $x_n \not \in C$. :)

Take such sequence. Let $z_n$ be the projection of $x_n$ on $C$. Now, let $y_n \not \in C$ be the point on the line connecting $x_n$ and $z_n$, distance $1$ apart from $C$. You can prove that $y_n$ converges to some point $y$, which is distance $1$ from $C$. What is more, since the projection of each $y_n$ in $z_n$, and $z_n \to z$, you can conclude that $y$ is the sought point!

Note that the above still needs some work to be done. Treat this as an exercise.

Comment: more simply, can I just set $a=z+\frac{z}{||z||}$ ? Thanks for your clear and helpful answer :)

Comment: I'm not sure... What is $a$?

Comment: a point outside $a$ such that its projection is $z$

Comment: Ah, now I see. Then I think it's not so easy. If $C$ is a square (centred at $(0,0)$, sidelength $1$), and $z$ is a point on the boundary, but *not* the midpoint nor a vertex, then I think a different choice of $a$ is needed.

Comment: I mentioned this point according to this reasoning. Let $x_n$ with $x_n \rightarrow z$ and $z_n$ the projection of $x_n$ on $C$ By continuity of the projection and since $z \in C$, $z_n \rightarrow z$. We want $y_n$ such that $y_n$ belongs to the line connecting $x_n$ and $z_n$. Hence $y_n=t x_n+ z_n$ for some $t \in \mathbb R$. For distance purposes, $||y_n-z_n||=1$ hence $t=\frac{1}{||x_n||}$ Then $y_n \rightarrow z+\frac{z}{||z||}$

Comment: I think you want the equation: $y_n = t (x_n-z_n) + z_n$, or equivalently $y_n = t x_n + (1-t)z_n$. Then, $t = 1/||x_n-y_n||$, but you run into trouble when you try to apply this formula "in the limit", because $x_n - y_n \to 0$.